# How to input two numbers from user in C on Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

I've been trying to make a program to input two numbers from the user.
The XCode application is showing error as

> Data argument not used by format string

How am I supposed to get over this? 
please help 
thanks

[image: example]

Comment: Please post the code as text *in the question* not as a photo.

Comment: printf("ENTER NUMBER 1 " , num1);

Comment: scanf("%d" , &num1);

Comment: int num1; \\ I have declared this function before using the printf statement.

Comment: `int num 1;` is not a function. It is a variable. It has not been initialised with any value, so in your comment below an answer, that accounts for the strange result. Until you specifically initialise a locally defined variable, it's value will have no use, whatever it happens to be. It can't have *no value*, so in your case it just happened to be `1606422582`. That's why in my answer below, I recommend not printing this useless value, until *after* you have called `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have a supplied a data argument which is not matched by any format specifiers. You have not yet entered any values for these two variables, so rather than adding `%d` format, which would cause *undefined behaviour*, it is better to delete the argument(s).

You can change the statements to be

```
printf("ENTER A NUMBER1 ");
...
printf("ENTER A NUMBER2 ");
```

Comment: Can you please show me the required syntax for this?

Comment: The syntax is what you have, without the `, num1` and the `, num2` in the first two `printf` calls. I can't copy/paste, since you only supplied a screenshot. The compiler has issued a warning, not an error. the unnecessary arguments will simply be ignored in this case.

Comment: @stek `puts` prints a `newline` but there isn't one in the `printf`. If you want to flush the output (which `newline` would do, but you don't want one), use `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: Oh, I've never noticed this, because I always printed strings with '\n' in end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just type `%d` inside the `("Here is my number %d",Num)`

You can find more formats here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree. init the int is also important.

Comment: The compiler is not showing any error but the output is as follows " ENTER NUMBER1 1606422582 "